# Le mot « chef » au féminin ?

Tags: genre, professions

Je souhaite écrire, formellement, une phrase qui commence par :

> Madame la chef du service XXXX

Est-ce que c'est correct ?

En effectuant une recherche en ligne, j'ai trouvé qu'au Quebec et en Suisse francophone, on peut dire « cheffe ». Mais dans mon cas, c'est un pays francophone en dehors des deux pays précités.

Comment: En France, "cheffe" me choque. "La chef" semble correct...

Comment: Contrairement à ce qu'on dit, au Québec on n'a pas retenu l'usage de [_cheffe_](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=4706), _chef_ étant épicène. On lira aussi avec intérêt [ceci](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=4015). Merci.

Comment: Il me semble que chez les scouts, on dit la "cheftaine", un mix entre chef et capitaine.

Comment: "cheftaine" existait avant les scouts mais le mot n’a gardé que ce sens-là aujourd’hui. Le fait que "cheffe" choque est une affaire d’habitude, "avocate", "aviatrice" et "étudiante" ont également en leur temps beaucoup choqué, avant de rentrer dans l’usage.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

La féminisation pour des emplois techniques ou par familiarité de *chef* est ***la chef***, donc l'exemple donné dans la question est correct, même si une envie de féminiser à tout prix donne à lire çà et là ce que *[l'académie française](http://academie-francaise.fr/actualites/feminisation-des-noms-de-metiers-fonctions-grades-et-titres) (en fin de page)* réprouve
 :

> Il convient tout d’abord de rappeler que les seuls féminins français en -eure (prieure, supérieure...) sont ceux qui proviennent de comparatifs latins en -or. Aussi faut-il éviter absolument des néologismes tels que professeure, ingénieure, auteure, docteure, proviseure, procureure, rapporteure, réviseure, etc. Certaines formes, parfois rencontrées, sont d’autant plus absurdes que les féminins réguliers correspondants sont parfaitement attestés. Ainsi chercheure à la place de chercheuse, instituteure à la place d’institutrice. ***On se gardera de même d’user de néologismes*** comme agente, **cheffe**, maîtresse de conférences, écrivaine, autrice... L’oreille autant que l’intelligence grammaticale devraient prévenir contre de telles ***aberrations lexicales***.

---

**Mode et usage**

Il y a une tendance récente à vouloir donner à la femme la place qui lui revient de fait, et de s'attaquer aux symboles comme le neutre et le masculin qui ont la même orthographe ; considérer masculin ce qui est neutre par usage est un autre moyen de mener ce combat vers l'égalité.

À moins que la personne écrive sa fonction avec un 'neutre féminisée', comme cité dans l'extrait ci-dessus, il est d'usage d'appliquer la féminisation à l'article seulement.

Et quand, enfin en 1982, un homme a réussi son examen de *sage femme*, quel chambardement dans les consciences, on est allé cherché *maïeuticien* ou *accoucheur* pour ne pas dé-viriliser 1% des hommes qui choisissent cette profession.

Il ne faut donc pas mépriser cette recherche d'égalité homme-femme, sans pour autant refuser le neutre :

- **le** (masculin) chef (neutre) sera reç**u** le ...
- **la** (féminin) chef (neutre) sera reç**ue** le ...

... à chaque fois, c'est l'article qui donne le genre et le neutre donne la qualité.

Comment: L'academie française participe au sexisme linguistique de la langue française et ne peut donc être utilisée comme référence.

Answer (score 3):

Depuis quelques temps, en France, la recommandation officielle du [Haut-Conseil à L'Égalité](http://www.haut-conseil-egalite.gouv.fr/) est d'utiliser *cheffe* au lieu de *chef* pour désigner une femme ([pdf des recommandations](http://www.haut-conseil-egalite.gouv.fr/IMG/pdf/guide_pour_une_communication_publique_sans_stereotype_de_sexe_vf_2016_11_02.compressed.pdf) ).

On remarquera que c'est aussi la dénomination *cheffe de cabinet* qui est utilisée par le journal officiel de la République française ([un exemple](https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/affichTexte.do?cidTexte=JORFTEXT000037460671) parmi d'autres).

Il me semble donc que, surtout dans un cadre officiel, l'usage de *cheffe* soit recommandé.